# String extension with constraint

Tags: swift, string, generics, protocols, extension-methods

I'm trying to create an extension to (non generic) String Type and add a variable of type string to return some format, but also have a constraint so that not every string can simply use it.

Can it be done using a protocol?
What are the preferred ways to go about achieving that basically.

Thanks!

Additional info:

I was considering a type constraint so perhaps something like this:

```
protocol Formattable {
    var formatted: String  { get }
}

extension String where Self: Formattable {
    var formatted: String {
      return self + "123".uppercased()
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure it's even the right way to do it and also I get an error:

```
'where' clause cannot be applied to a non-generic top-level declaration
```

Maybe just create a custom class with a formatting function is better? Sorry for the confusion and hope that it makes a bit more sense.

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: You can use StringProtocol but as already mentioned by Martin you need to post more details about what you are trying to achieve. You might need some constrains to provide the required functionality.

Comment: Regarding not allow a String to use it that's not how the language works.

Comment: Can you be more clear what you're trying to do? Are you saying you want to call a calculated var of type String on String.Type that returns a formatted string?

Comment: Well there is no `String` type that conforms to `Formattable`. What you need is `extension String: Formattable {` but as I said any String would be able to "use" the formatted property.